# USE SQL to SUBSTR an Integer

Tags: sql

I am attempting to UNION two tables and in am trying to return the data where only authors and editors who have the 3rd and 4th numbers of their ssn are returned. I am trying to get this without using pattern matching characters (i.e. '%') etc.
I am not getting an error but the results that are returned as I see the entire table and SQL is returning wrong data. Any help is appreciated!

SQL

```
SELECT 'employee', firstname, lastname, ssn
    FROM employee
UNION 
SELECT 'manager', firstname, lastname, ssn
    FROM manager
WHERE SUBSTR(ssn, 3,4) = '25';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT 'employee', firstname, lastname, ssn
FROM employee
WHERE ssn LIKE '25%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'manager', firstname, lastname, ssn
FROM manager
WHERE ssn LIKE '25%';
```

Note that `UNION ALL` is much preferable to `UNION` because it does not remove duplicates.

Comment: Duly noted on the UNION ALL tip, also, is there a way to get the same results without using the pattern matching charactert (i.e %, _) etc? What is the characters I am trying to return in the ssn are in the middle of the number? I will correct my question.

Comment: @TRS7 . . . That is why you want to use `LIKE`.  You can use `LIKE '%25%` or `LIKE __25%'` or whatever to get the pattern you want.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers but is there a way to achieve the same result without using the '%,_' characters ?

Comment: @TRS7 . . . Yes, your question has the logic in it.  I just prefer `LIKE` for this purpose, because it at least has the hope of using an index.